# NSDataの値を変更したい。

Tags: swift

NSDataを書き換えたいのですがうまくいきません。

```
var baseData = NSData()
baseData = XXXXX() ※ 別のメソッドからNSDataを取得

var ptr = UnsafePointer<構造体（C言語の型にキャスト）> (baseData.bytes).memory
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&ptr.test.info.0) { infoPtr in
    for index in 0..<infoの配列数{
        print("old\(infoPtr[index].longdata)")
        infoPtr[index].longdata = infoPtr[index].longdata.bigEndian
        print("new\(infoPtr[index].longdata)")
    }
}

var ptr2 = UnsafePointer<構造体（C言語の型にキャスト）> (baseData.bytes).memory
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&ptr2.test.info.0) { infoPtr in
    for index in 0..<infoの配列数{
        print("check \(infoPtr[index].longdata)")※再度読みだし
    }
}
```

このような形で一部のデータをエンディアン変換しています。
変換前後の値をログで見ると変わっていることを確認できるのですが
再度読み出しても値が変わっていません。

NSDataの一部を書き換えるにはどうするのがよいのでしょうか・・・

□追記
構造体

```
typedef struct {
 short info[10];
 int infoint;
} INFO_STR;

typedef struct {
 INFO_STR test;
 int testint;
} TEST_STR;
```

Comment: `NSData`は書き換え不能型ですので、「`NSData`以外のデータ構造を使って内容を書き換え、それを元に別の`NSData`を作成する」か、または「`NSData`の内容をコピーした`NSMutableData`を作成し、その内容を書き換える」かのどちらかの形にしないといけないでしょう。あなたが質問中のコードに示された情報から例を作ってみようと思ったのですが、`ptr.test.info.0`と言ったかなり面倒なことをしているのに「構造体（C言語の型にキャスト）」「infoの配列数」と肝心なところで中身がわからないので、コードの書きようがありません。それらの内容をもう少しはっきりさせることはできませんか？またC言語のstructを使った時によくある「可変長配列」的なことをやっているのであれば、話はさらに複雑になります。上記の「どちらか」だけを読んでご自分で解決できないのであれば、もう少し具体的な情報がないと、回答を書くのは非常に困難ですね。

Comment: 構造体を追加してみました。infoがC言語の構造体で配列となっており、swiftからはタプルでアクセスしかできない状態となっています。NSMutableDataを作成した場合、簡単に部分的に設定が可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。書きかけていた回答をその内容に合わせて修正中です。今しばらくお待ちください。(どなたかがもっと素晴らしい回答を先に上げられた場合にはボツにしますので悪しからず。)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

追記していただいたコードを元に2通りの方法でコードを書いてみました。構造体の定義を見ても、`longdata`と言う名称のメンバーを持つ別の構造体は見当たらないので、そこらへんは省略しました。

以下の記述を見る前に、元の構造体が、

```
struct INFO_STR {
    var info: (Int16, Int16, Int16, Int16, Int16, Int16, Int16, Int16, Int16, Int16)
    var infoint: Int32
}

struct TEST_STR {
    var test: INFO_STR
    var testint: Int32
}
```

…のようにSwiftにimportされているのを確認しておいてください。

---

(NSData以外のデータ構造を使って内容を書き換え、それを元に別のNSDataを作成する)
こちらの方があなたの元のコードに近い書き方になります。

```
let count = 10 //infoの配列数

let baseData = XXXXX() //使いもしないインスタンス(`NSData()`)を作るのは避けるべき

var editingData = UnsafePointer<TEST_STR>(baseData.bytes).memory //`editingData`は`baseData`の中身のコピーになる
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&editingData.test.info) {wholeInfoPtr in //tupleを配列っぽくアクセスするときのより安全な方法
    let infoPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>(wholeInfoPtr) //<-Int32になってました(失礼しました)
    for index in 0..<count {
        print("old\(infoPtr[index])") //提示された構造体には`longdata`なるメンバーはないので書き換え
        infoPtr[index] = infoPtr[index].bigEndian
        print("new\(infoPtr[index])")
    }
}
//ここまで実行が終わると`editingData`の内容が書き換わっている(`NSData`の内容ではない)
//上の`editingData`の内容を含む`NSData`を新たに作る
let editedData = NSData(bytes: &editingData, length: sizeof(TEST_STR))
//新しく作った方のデータの内容を再表示
var showingData = UnsafePointer<TEST_STR> (editedData.bytes).memory //実際にはローカル変数`showingData`にコピーされた内容を表示する
withUnsafePointer(&showingData.test.info) {wholeInfoPtr in
    let infoPtr = UnsafePointer<Int16>(wholeInfoPtr)
    for index in 0..<count {
        print("check \(infoPtr[index])") //※再度読みだし
    }
}
```

---

(NS‌​Dataの内容をコピーしたNSMutableDataを作成し、その内容を書き換える)

```
let count = 10 //infoの配列数

let baseData = XXXXX()

let mutableData = NSMutableData(data: baseData) //`baseData`の書き換え可能なコピーを作成する

let mutablePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutableData.mutableBytes) //書き換え可能領域の先頭アドレスを取得
//`Int8`を使っているのはバイト単位でのアドレス計算用

let offsetToInfo = 0 //`TEST_STR`内での`info`の位置を手計算で算出しておく

let infoPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>(mutablePtr + offsetToInfo) //最初の`info`のアドレスを取得
//`Int16`は構造体`INFO_STR`中の`info`のデータ型

for index in 0..<count {
    print("old\(infoPtr[index])") //提示された構造体には`longdata`なるメンバーはないので書き換え
    infoPtr[index] = infoPtr[index].bigEndian
    print("new\(infoPtr[index])")
}
//ここまで実行が終わると`mutableData`の内容が書き換わっている

//新しく作った方のデータの内容を再表示
var showingData = UnsafePointer<TEST_STR> (mutableData.bytes).memory
withUnsafePointer(&showingData.test.info) {wholeInfoPtr in
    let infoPtr = UnsafePointer<Int16>(wholeInfoPtr)
    for index in 0..<count {
        print("check \(infoPtr[index])") //※再度読みだし
    }
}
```

`NSMutableData`は`NSData`のサブクラスなので、`mutableData`を「書き換え済みの`baseData`として使用することができるようになります。

---

(編集メモ)
編集前のコードも「経験上このやり方で動く」というコードだったのですが、Swiftの意味論的に
「より確実に動く」コードに修正させていただきました。

(編集メモ2)
いただいた例では`info`は`Int16`のtupleなのに、`Int32`としてしまっていたところが残っていました。修正しましたので、古いコードをコピーされていた場合はお気をつけください。

それも含めて何かご意見等ありましたら、コメントにてお願いします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。前者のコードがイメージしていたものに近かったためこちらで試してみました。うまくいきました！後者のコードについても試してみます。（とりいそぎ、お礼と結果の報告まで・・・）

Comment: @kanko さん、丁寧なコメントをいただいた後で申し訳ないのですが、まだデータ型の誤りが残っていました。本家のStack Overflowのとある記事を見て「ちょっとした改良」をしたつもりだったのですが、チェックが不十分で失礼しました。すでにご自身のコードに組み込むに当たってお気づきだったかも知れませんが、ポインターの誤りは少々間違っていても動いているように見えるときがあると言う厄介なものになります。修正後の内容(1行の中で`Int32`→`Int32`の書き換えのみ)をご確認の上でお試しください。